# characters in login screen replaced by question marks

Tags: macbook-pro, display, macos, screen, login

My log-in screen appears with question marks instead of the usual text. (See screen shot - I have removed my log-in name from the picture).  I am using MacOS Sierra 10.12.3 on a MacBook Pro (early 2011).
[image]

Comment: What language text encoding are you using?

Comment: English (Australia)

Comment: Booting in Safe Mode gives the correct characters

Comment: The issue is in your text encoding, let me post an answer soon

Comment: This happens to me after my mac get somewhat slow and unresponsive

Comment: None of these answers worked for me. Anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to missing fonts. (Where the system picks a poor choice to substitute for the “missing characters”). If you use font management software, be sure to reinstall or re-enable the system fonts.

> **1.** Run validations with Font Book
>
> Launch Font Book and press command-A to select all fonts. Then from
>   the "File" menu select "Validate Fonts" and wait for the results in
>   the font validation window. Keep in mind that even though you may find
>   minor problems with your current fonts, its best to follow the saying
>   "if it's not broken then don't fix it", and leave well-enough alone
>   unless you're experiencing problems.
>
> **2.** Clear the font cache
>
> In OS X, fonts are handled by the Apple Type Server process, which
>   stores commonly used fonts in a cache for quick access. If there is
>   corruption in this cache then you may experience a variety of
>   troubles. To clear the cache, in pre-Leopard versions of OS X go to
>   the /Macintosh HD/Library/Caches/ folder and remove the
>   "com.apple.ATS" file. After doing this, restart the system.
>
> For OS X 10.5 and later, you cannot easily access the user and global
>   font caches, but you can use Apple's "atsutil" terminal command to
>   manage the ATS process. Open "Terminal" and enter the following
>   commands to clear the user (or global) databases and restart the
>   server:
>
> atsutil databases -removeUser atsutil server -shutdown atsutil server
>   -ping
>
> NOTE: Use "sudo atsutil databases -remove" instead of the first
>   command to remove the database for all users.
>
> **3.** Avoid older font formats
>
> If you can, avoid ".dfont" and "Type 1 PostScript" fonts. This
>   suggestion may depend on the requirements for various programs, but if
>   you have an older font suite that you are thinking about installing,
>   it may run into problems with newer programs so you might consider
>   getting an updated version of the suite before installing. Granted you
>   can always try, but there is the potential that older font formats can
>   cause problems so we recommend you stick to the more modern ".ttf" and
>   ".ttc" fonts.
>
> **4.** Manually clear out duplicates
>
> Font Book has an option to "Resolve Duplicates" (available in the
>   "Edit" menu), but this is limited in functionality and may not remove
>   the specific font duplicate which you desire to remove. As such, the
>   best approach to managing duplicate fonts is to do it manually
>   (tedious, but effective if done correctly). In Font Book, you can use
>   the "Show Font info" option (command-I) to see information about a
>   selected font, and especially where the font is located on your
>   system. Doing this for your duplicate fonts will allow you to select
>   which one to remove, either by removing it from its font folder, or by
>   right-clicking it and selecting "Disable".

**From:** https://www.cnet.com/news/font-problems-and-management-in-os-x/

Comment: I would delete the part about text encoding, which has nothing to do with this problem.  It's a font issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to Applications/Font Book/ and do File > Restore Standard Fonts and restart.